# configure driver mongocxx on linux mint

Tags: c++, mongodb

i begin a new projet in c++ with Qt and i want to use mongodb,
i have installed mongo and the libs but when i want to configure the driver "mongo-cxx-driver-r3.9.0", i have a problem on the **step 3** on "https://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/linux/".

the error :

```
fatal: ni ceci ni aucun de ses répertoires parents n'est un 
dépôt git : .git
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/sup4/mongo-cxx-driver- 
r3.9.0/etc/calc_release_version.py", line 349, in <module>
RELEASE_VER = main()
File "/home/sup4/mongo-cxx-driver- 
r3.9.0/etc/calc_release_version.py", line 304, in main
head_commit_short = check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--revs- 
only',
File "/home/sup4/mongo-cxx-driver- 
r3.9.0/etc/calc_release_version.py", line 110, in check_output
raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(ret, args[0])
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'git' returned non-zero 
exit status 128.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:246 (message):
BUILD_VERSION not specified and could not be calculated (script 
invocation
failed); specify in CMake command, -DBUILD_VERSION=<version>
```

version python : 3.10.12 \n
version cmake : 3.28.1

Comment: Please post text as text and not as image. It wastes a lot of space and nobody can copy paste it. So please remove the images. Thanks!

Comment: ok, i have change image to txt, i have search in the code of the driver, the problem would come of the file calc_release_version.py on the method "check_head_tag", i edit the question for post the code of the driver

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to build the package found at https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/releases/download/r3.9.0/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.9.0.tar.gz in an Ubuntu based docker machine and found the same issue.

Weirdly enough, I was able to compile it once without any issues. I ran into this on the second try. (I did slightly change the base image though.)

Anyways, I was able to start compilation after adding the following options to my `cmake` command:

```
RUN \
    cd /tmp \
    && tar -xzf mongo-cxx-driver.tar.gz \
    && cd mongo-cxx-driver-r3.9.0/build \
    && cmake .. \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DMONGOCXX_OVERRIDE_DEFAULT_INSTALL_PREFIX=OFF \
        -DBUILD_VERSION=3.9.0 \
    && cmake --build . \
    && cmake --build . --target install \
    && rm -rf /tmp/mongo-cxx-driver-r3.9.0
```

What made it work was `-DBUILD_VERSION=3.9.0`. I am still unsure if this is the correct way of making it work. So, it would be great if someone with more knowledge can validate this answer.